# What's so standard about standard input or standard output?

Tags: input, standards, output

Why can't they just call it input or output?

This is more of a historical question I think than a programming question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about History of Terms.

Answer (score 1):

Read this document
[The ins and outs of standard input/output](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2001/jw-0302-java101.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because you can change how a program's IO behaves, e.g. reading bytes over a network or writing to a file. STDIN and STDOUT (and STDERR) are the defaults. Or, if you will, the standards.